# How to add a calculated column which marks month names with sequential numbers?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table in a Power BI report that displays a combination of year and month like this:

```
Name
----------
2021 - JAN
2021 - JUN
2021 - MAR
2021 - OCT
2022 - JAN
2022 - JUN
2022 - MAR
```

This table (let's call it table2) is created from another table in the same report using some DAX that looks like this:

```
table2 = all(table1[Name])
```

What I want to do is add a column to table2 which displays the order of the values in the table as a numerical sequence, like this:

```
Name       |Order
-----------|-----
2021 - JAN | 1
2021 - JUN | 3
2021 - MAR | 2
2021 - OCT | 4
2022 - JAN | 5
2022 - JUN | 7
2022 - MAR | 6
```

Table1 will be added to as work takes place, so '2022 - OCT' will be added this October etc; the numerical sequence will need to accomodate this.

For context, the names refer to project work taking place four times a year, so the month will only ever be Jan, Mar, Jun, or Oct.

Does anyone know how best to do this please?

Comment: Edited my answer to show a simple DAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DAX**

- Convert the `Name` column to real dates
  *may need a different code if needs to be internationally aware*
- Use `RANKX` to return the order by date

```
    Order = RANKX('Table',CONVERT([Name],DATETIME),,asc)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most direct way would be to create a *matching table*. Simply by creating the table and filling it in with the "Enter data" button in the ribbon.

It should look like this:

| Month_short | Month_seq |
| --- | --- |
| JAN | 1 |
| MAR | 3 |
| JUN | 6 |
| OCT | 10 |

Let's call it "Month_match".

Then, in `Table2`, you create a new column using this code:

```
Order =
VAR month_short = MID(Table2[Name], 8, 3)
RETURN
LOOKUPVALUE(
    Month_match[Month_seq],
    Month_match[Month_short],
    month_short
)
```

What this code does:

- It creates a variable that is just the part of `Name` containing the *month short*.
- It use the `LOOKUPVALUE` function to find it in the newly created table `Month_match` and returns the corresponding value in `Month_seq`